# I am getting mismatch in json data after parsing it from API

Tags: java, json, api

I am trying to parse a json api for Covid19. The link is available in the code . The data I am getting does not match with the original JSON file.(for eg: there is a mismatch in the stats for the district "Rohtas" and many more)

```
 public static void getAllDistrictsInfo()
        {
            ArrayList<StateDetails> states = new ArrayList<StateDetails>();
            try{
            URL url = new URL("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json");//your url i.e fetch data from .
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);


            Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            String inline = "";
            while(sc.hasNext())
            {
            inline+=sc.nextLine();
            }

            JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parse.parse(inline);
            ArrayList<String> set = new ArrayList<String>(jobj.keySet());

           for(Iterator iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) 
           {
                String key = (String) iterator.next();
                JSONObject distdata = (JSONObject) jobj.get(key);
                JSONObject dists = (JSONObject) distdata.get("districtData");
                System.out.println(key);

                ArrayList<String> set2 = new ArrayList<String>(dists.keySet());
                for(Iterator itr = set2.iterator();itr.hasNext();)
                {
                    String key2 = (String) itr.next();
                    JSONObject district = (JSONObject) dists.get(key2);
                    System.out.println(key2);
                    System.out.println(district);
                }
                System.out.println("************");

            }

            conn.disconnect();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- " + e);
        }


        }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Executed your code and printed the JSON vs Downloaded the JSON from the site both JSONs are identifcal

Comment: try to print the district data in the code. It does not match with the actual json file.....some examples of mismatch are : Rohtas , Gaya , Patna etc......